# Spring MVC + ApacheTiles 3

Tags: spring, apache-tiles

Please help me to find the mistake.

I'm trying to learn a webbapp using Spring MVC and Tiles but my Tiles template applying only to the first layer URL (e.g. /contacts) but not to the second layer URL (e.g. /contacts/2). Here is my code...

ContactController.java

```
    @RequestMapping("/contacts")
    @Controller
    public class ContactController{

    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model uiModel) {
    List<Contact> contacts = contactService.findAll();
    uiModel.addAttribute ("contacts", contacts);
    return "list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path ="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable ("id") Long id, Model uiModel){
    Contact contact = contactService.findById(id);
    uiModel.addAttribute("contact", contact);
    return "show";
    }
```

This is my common Tiles definitions

layouts.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="default" template="WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx">
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jspx"/>
       <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

This is my "body" definitions

views.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="list">
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/list.jspx" />
    </definition>
    <definition extends="default" name="show">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/show.jspx"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

This is my first layer URL (/contacts) page "list".jspx. Tiles tempale work with this page properly.

list.jspx

```
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <spring:message code="label.ContactList" var="labelContactList"/>
    <spring:message code="label.ContactFirstName" var="labelContactFirstName"/>
    <spring:message code="label.ContactLastName" var="labelContactLastName"/>
    <spring:message code="label.ContactBirthDate" var="labelContactBirthDate"/>
    <spring:url value="/contacts" var="showContactUrl"/>

    <jsp:element name="text">

       <jsp:body>
          <H1>${labelContactList}</H1>
            <c:if test="${not empty contacts}">
                <TABLE>
                    <THEAD>
                        <TR>
                            <TH>${labelContactFirstName}</TH>
                            <TH>${labelContactLastName}</TH>
                            <TH>${labelContactBirthDate}</TH>
                        </TR>
                    </THEAD>
                    <TBODY>
                        <c:forEach items="${contacts}" var="c">
                            <TR>



  //This is the reference to second layer URL                                

<TD>
<A href="${showContactUrl}/${c.id}">${c.firstName}</A> 
</TD>

<TD>${c.lastName}</TD>

<TD>
<joda:format value="${c.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</TD>
                            </TR>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </TBODY>
                </TABLE>
            </c:if>
        </jsp:body>
```

When I try to open page with contact details from this page (e.g /contacts/4) browser show me

**"HTTP Status 404 - /SpringWebTest/contacts/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx

type Status report

message /SpringWebTest/contacts/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.27"**

**I don't understand why app can see Tiles template "default".jspx from layer "/contacts" and can't see from URL layer "/contacts/{id}"?**

Comment: I solved this problem, just replaced my template .jspx page to the root "webapp/default.jspx"